# Is $ P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R $ in DNF?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know a single conjunction or disjunction is already in both DNF and CNF but what about $ P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R $?

I know it is in CNF but I'm unsure if it is in DNF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a DNF formula with a single clause.

Comment: Thanks, could I think of it as $ (P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R) \vee (P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R) $, in order to see the DNF clearly? Idempotency simplifying it back to the original formula.

Comment: If it helps you, sure. However be aware that a formula $\psi$ being in DNF/CNF is a syntactic property rather than a semantic one. If you create a new formula $\psi'$ in DNF/CNF from $\psi$ such that both formulas are (sematically) equivalent you can only conclude syntactic properties of $\psi$ by inspecting the process of obtaining $\psi'$, which might not always be possible.